# Whitelisting URL endpoints to log in Flask API

Tags: python, flask, logging, wsgi

I have a Flask API that is being flooded with request spam, so the log is full of nonsense. I want to whitelist the endpoints contained within the API to log requests. I have implemented a function that will work for this purpose, which was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56959585/skip-flask-logging-for-one-endpoint/57413338#57413338).

```
def restrict_access_logs():
    parent_log_request = serving.WSGIRequestHandler.log_request

    permitted = ['hello','getEvidencesByProductID','getEvidencesByModifierEventTime','getEvidences']
    permitted = [rule.endpoint for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules()]

    def log_request(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if any(re.match(f"/api/v1/{str(endpoint)}.*$", self.path) for endpoint in permitted):
            parent_log_request(self, *args, **kwargs)

    serving.WSGIRequestHandler.log_request = log_request
```

The first "permitted" list was typed manually and works as intended. The second is my attempt to grab all of the endpoints so I don't have to manually enter each new endpoint. The second list doesn't work and doesn't display any requests in the log.

I've set up a test endpoint to see what is returned and it looks like this:

```
@app.route('/testpoint', methods=['GET'])
def testpoint():
    ep_list = [rule.endpoint for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules()]
    ep_str = ", ".join(ep_list)
    return ep_str
```

And this is the output of this endpoint:

> getEvidencesByModifierEventTime, getEvidencesByFuzzAndTime, getEvidencesByProductID, getEvidencesByFuzz, getEvidences, hello, stopServer, testpoint, static

Why doesn't this method work? I'm at a loss as to the difference between these two lists.

Comment: comapre the both list in the function and see if they are equal or not

Comment: @sahasrara62 It says they are

Answer (score 1):

I realized I called the restrict_access_logs() function too early, before the program could read the endpoints. Moving the function call to the bottom of the file made it work.